# Ruby array search, returning either a result with a good score or the last result

Tags: ruby, array, search

I have an array of hashes, each of which has two attributes: `"title"` and `"Zscore"`. I want to return either the result of `find` or the last element. This can be done with:

```
a = array.select{|i| i["title"] == "some title"}
b = a.find{|i| i["Zscore"].to_f >= 5} || a.last
```

Is there an elegant way to put the conditional inside the block, something like the following?

> ```
> array.select{|i| i["title"] == "some title"}.find{|i| i["Zscore"].to_f >= 5 || last}
> ```

Any built-in method? Any ideas of one-liner that is nicer than the following?

```
array.select{|i| i["title"] == "some title"}.find{|i| i["Zscore"].to_f >= 5} ||
array.select{|i| i["title"] == "some title"}.last
```

Comment: **Why**? Why would you want a built-in method, and why would you think it would be better than the **two characters** `||`? What you have right now is *already* elegant. I can't imagine what you think you'll accomplish by moving the conditional inside the block, except to make the code less readable and *less* elegant.

Comment: @meagar The OP's intention is not clearly expressed, but I suspect the real intention is to avoid intermediate variable assignment `a =` and doing it in a  chain style.

Comment: @sawa That moves the question "Why?", but it doesn't answer it.

Comment: @meagar Yeah. I don't think it is worth doing it.

Comment: @meagar **Why?** because ruby provides many elegant one-liners and having all of `array.select{|i| i["title"] == "some title"}.find{|i| i["Zscore"].to_f >= 5} || array.select{|i| i["title"] == "some title"}.last` is long and unreadable.
As for the original tag of `ruby-on-rails`, it is within a Rails app. Rails provides methods such as `first_or_create` and I have wondered about the existence of a method of such kind that might come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

You can always define your own custom method to refactor your code in the `Array` class:

```
class Array
  def find_or_last(&block)
    find(&block) || last 
  end
end
```

And use it like this:

```
array.select { |i| i['title'] == 'some title' }.find_or_last { |i| i['Zscore'].to_f >= 5 }
```

You can also use [procs or lambdas](https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/18-blocks/lessons/64-blocks-procs-lambdas) to achieve this.

Comment: Any developer on my team who tried to introduce this code to a project would immediately have a his pull request denied and be given a stern talking to about monkey-patching core classes.

Comment: @meagar Unless Spätzle is in your team, this comment has nothing to do with a correct robust answer, provided by Wikiti.

Comment: @mudasobwa Answers can be correct in that they solve the problem, but *absolutely terrible* in that they glaringly violate established best practices for no discernible reason.

Comment: @meagar Then I believe it worth it to mention best practices rather than your personal leadership preferences in first place.

Comment: @meagar I don't like extending core classes either, but the OP asked for an `elegant` or `one-liner` solution. If he's working on a personal or basic project, this solution should work for him.

Comment: I am NOT working on a personal / basic project and monkey-patching core classes would make my boss, just as @meagar said, reject my work. The whole purpose was having a nice one-liner (which eventually reduces db queries) W/O patching. If patching was legitimate for this, I wouldn't even have bothered asking this question.

Answer (score 1):

I have assumed `a` is not needed for some unspecified purpose.

This is a way of achieving the desired result with a single pass through the array.

```
last = nil
array.find do |h|
  next unless h["title"] == "some title"
  last = h
  h["Zscore"].to_f >= 5
end || last
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this using [`Enumerable#detect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect):

```
array = [{"title"=>"Foo", "Zscore" => "2.0"},
         {"title"=>"Bar", "Zscore" => "5.0"},
         {"title"=>"some title", "Zscore" => "2.0"}]

result = (t = array.select {|i| i["title"] == "some title"})
             .detect (-> {t.last} ) {|i| i["Zscore"].to_f >= 5}

#=> {"title"=>"some title", "Zscore"=>"2.0"}
```

The parameter passed to `detect` is the `ifnone` method that will be evaluated and returned if `detect` could not find any matching element.

Comment: You are close. But this is not correct. It will give you a wrong answer when the last element of `array` does not satisfy the first condition, and the default has to be used.

Comment: The goal is not to return `array.last`, it is to return `array.selet { |a| a['title'] ==  'some_title' }.last`

Comment: @meagar Okay, I was working on the solution as sawa already pointed out the problem.  Have fixed it now.

Comment: You can simply give up doing it with method chain, but use the default. That would still be an improvement over the OP's code.

Comment: You haven't eliminated the intermediate variable, you've just wrapped it in parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Variation with `Enumerator#each_with_object` (O(n)):

```
array.each_with_object({}) { |el, hsh| el['title'] == 'some title' && hsh.replace(el) && el['Zscore'].to_f >= 5.0 && (break el) }
```

Some kind of "functional" style. Maybe, somewhat too verbose but readable. Can't assess its elegance yet.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with using a local variable, but you can always transform variables to chains with a let abstraction. Ruby has no such abstraction, but you can create it it yourself (it has a myriad of names, I like `as`):

```
class Object
  def as
    yield self
  end
end

result = xs.select { |x| x["title"] == "some title" }.
  as { |ys| ys.find { |y| y["Zscore"].to_f >= 5 } || ys.last }
```